# Google App Script Debugger gives TypeError but running it doesn't give the error

Tags: google-apps-script

The Google App Script Debugger gives a `TypeError: This operation is not allowed.` in this line:

```
var rowNum = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().getRowIndex() - 1;
```

As far as I read, this line is perfectly legal. I've also tried using the identical `getRow()` method, but the error still persists. I put a breakpoint on it before, and ever since then it gives the error. But when I run the script, it works well in that part. I wrote this as a spreadsheet-contained script, and I was even able to debug the script before. How should I fix this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: As a workaround, I put a lot of `Logger.log()` methods around my code, which works, but I'd still like to have the debugger.

Comment: "This operation is not allowed" sounds clear to me.

Comment: Why is the operation not allowed when I have allowed access to my spreadsheet and have an active range to take its row index from? It's expected to return a number so I can subtract a number from it. What makes the operation not allowed? Also, the error is now gone from that line, but came to another line where I put a breakpoint, which again, doesn't give an error when it is run.